# draggable chart to edit value

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I don't know if it's possible, but is there a way to get a dynamic chart in excel.
I would like to drag up/down/right/left a column/pie part of my chart, and it will edit my table value.

An example is event better: 
Is there a way to do somthing like [That](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/drag-able-charts/creating-drag-able-charts.html)

Comment: Somewhat disappointingly, Excel used to have this functionality (at least with scatter plots) but removed it (in Excel 2010 I think, though it could have been earlier). With more recent versions it is doable but requires a nontrivial amount of code. See this for some ideas: http://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel/ Also, see this: https://blogs.office.com/2009/11/02/excel-add-in-for-manipulating-points-on-charts-mpoc/ I can't vouch for this add-in (I've never used it) but it seems like what you might want.

Comment: :(, btw thanks you for this information. I'll search for another solution then